# Django не отображает загруженную картинку

Tags: python-3.x, django

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True )
```

В url.py добавлено

```
    +static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

В settings.py добавлено

```
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

и ещё

```
'django.template.context_processors.media'
```

Шаблон

```
{%extends 'blog/base_blog.html'%}

{%block content%}
    <h1 class="mt-5">
        {{post.title}}
    </h1>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    {%if post.image%}
        <img src="{{MEDIA_ROOT}}{{post.image.url}}">
    {%endif%}
{%endblock%}
```

Загрузка изображений проходит без проблем и сохраняется в 'media/images'. 
При попытке отобразить на странице, выдает в терминале

```
"Not Found: /media/images/img.jpg". 
"GET /media/images/img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404"
```

Попробовал разные варианты решений из сети, но результата нет. Pillow установлена. Django 2.1.7

Comment: Во-первых, просто `<img src="{{ post.image.url }}">`. Во-вторых, `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: Debug = True. "Во-первых, просто <img src="{{ post.image.url }}">" - убрал. Хотя в некоторых статьях рекомендуют MEDIA_ROOT. Или я неправильно понял.

Comment: @Vladislav, используют или MEDIA_URL , или .url

Comment: В любом случае все равно не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, ошибка оказалась довольно глупой. Плохо почитал документацию. 
Строка,

```
 +static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

была прописана в url.py приложения, а нужно было прописать её в корневом url.py.